# How to sum two React props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

What I wanna do is sum two React props that contain values that the App is fetching from a database

Here's the props snippet

```
const GPBBatting = (props) => (
  <tr>
    <td>{props.player.Player}</td>
    <td>{props.player.G_GS.substring(0, 1)}</td>
    <td>{props.player.AB}</td>
    <td>{props.player.R}</td>
    <td>{props.player.H}</td>
    <td>{props.player.H2}</td>
    <td>{props.player.H3}</td>
    <td>{props.player.HR}</td>
    <td>{props.player.RBI}</td>
    <td>{props.player.SB_ATT}</td>
    <td>{props.player.BB}</td>
    <td>{props.player.SO}</td>
    <td>{props.player.BA}</td>
    <td>{props.player.OBP}</td>
    <td>{props.player.SLG}</td>

    <<<<<<I want the sum of OBP + SLG values here>>>>>

    <td>{props.player.TB}</td>
    <td>{props.player.SH}</td>
    <td>{props.player.SF}</td>
  </tr>
);
```

And here in this link is the complete code: https://www.paste.org/111710

Comment: What about just `{props.player.OBP + props.player.SLG}`? Or if they are strings `{parseInt(props.player.OBP) + parseInt(props.player.SLG)}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't this just `<td>{props.player.OBP + props.player.SLG}</td>`? Or if they're not numbers, `<td>{parseInt(props.player.OBP) + parseInt(props.player.SLG)}</td>`.

I'd recommend brushing up on your JS with something like [learnxinyminutes](http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/javascript/) or [Mozilla's excellent JS primers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects).

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Yeah I'm still pretty much a beginner and I've got a lot to learn.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what your setup is, but if GPBBAtting is your component, you can do:

```
const GPBBatting = (props) => (

const getPlayerSum = (a, b) => {
      const sumValue = a + b;
      return sumValue
}

return(
  <tr>
    <td>{props.player.Player}</td>
    <td>{props.player.G_GS.substring(0, 1)}</td>
    <td>{props.player.AB}</td>
    <td>{props.player.R}</td>
    <td>{props.player.H}</td>
    <td>{props.player.H2}</td>
    <td>{props.player.H3}</td>
    <td>{props.player.HR}</td>
    <td>{props.player.RBI}</td>
    <td>{props.player.SB_ATT}</td>
    <td>{props.player.BB}</td>
    <td>{props.player.SO}</td>
    <td>{props.player.BA}</td>
    <td>{props.player.OBP}</td>
    <td>{props.player.SLG}</td>

    {getPlayerSum(props.player.SLG, props.player.OBP)} // call a sum function here and pass the values you want to sum

    <td>{props.player.TB}</td>
    <td>{props.player.SH}</td>
    <td>{props.player.SF}</td>
  </tr>
)
);
```

You could do it a few ways, but I think this way is neatest because you keep the sum logic out of the return and the function is reusable if you want to sum other things.